# docker compose problem with GitHub repo on WSL

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Im trying to add a service to my docker compose file which pulls from a github repository.

the problem is to do so I need to enter the repo url with the **https://** at the start.
so what happens is it manages to pull the repo but than it can find the docker file because if the url is "https://github.com/some-rep" it will look for the docker file in "/var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount342870602/https:\github.com/some-rep/Dockerfile".
as you can see when it looks for the file it replaces "https://" with "https:".
I configured it so the docketfile will be called "Docker\file" and it was looking for "Docker/file" instead. so again "\\" is replaced with "/".

btw I was able to run it on mac and there it works.

is there a way to determine the build folder in docker compose or is there another solution?

Comment: ok suddenly working. i did not change a thing. I am not aware of any update that happened, but it is working. I don't know which go heard my prayers but thank you.